# Building a Windows executable from my Ruby app?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to be able to send a Ruby app to some colleagues without requiring them to install a Ruby interpreter. A single exe would be preferable.

I googled and found "RubyScript2Exe".

What are your experiences with that? Are there other such tools or are there better approaches altogether than building an exe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used it about 3 times and I haven't had any problems with it and I ran one of the apps on 10 servers and never had any issues. So, I think RubyScript2Exe is about as good as it gets for ruby.

Comment: RubyScript2Exe is very easy to use.  But it's good to mention that the executables are very slow to start up.

Comment: Ocra is the latest implementation of RubyScript2Exe. Stands for One Click Ruby Application

Answer (score 7):

_why's [Shoes](http://shoooes.net) framework lets you package the program as an executable for Mac or Windows that installs Shoes (contains a Ruby interpreter). Information about using the packager is [here](http://shoooes.net/about/raisins/). _why also gives hints about how he makes the Windows executable [here](http://hackety.org/2008/06/19/stampingExesAndDmgs.html).

Comment: So far I have been really pleased working with Shoes, i would recommend giving this a try.

Comment: After _why's disappearance, the links mentioned above are all offline. The new home of Shoes is at http://shoes.heroku.com/ and the source code is at http://github.com/shoes/shoes

Comment: The question conditions to not install ruby interpreter, and how come you expect shoes to be installed?

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget OCRA [1] which I used a couple of times and which Just Worked.
I used to create my exes with RubyScript2Exe as mentioned above but had problems when used with Ruby 1.9 [2].

[1] http://ocra.rubyforge.org/ 
[2] http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/343891

Answer (score 4):

There is another one called [Crate](http://github.com/copiousfreetime/crate/tree/master). You can find some information about it [here](http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/crate-packaging-your-ruby-application.html). However I haven't tested it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late to the party, but I found this question in my search for trying to do this myself (starting to use SO more and more as a primary resource).

Anyway, I have just had success with [exerb](http://exerb.sourceforge.jp/index.en.html), although I'd add a couple of notes:

- The web page says exerb runs on any platform.  That is true; however if you "compile" a program calls out to native code, then `exerb` will embed your system's native code (e.g. Linux `.so` files) into the .exe.  In practice, that means you have to build any significant app on Windows.
- The web page also says `ruby -r exerb/mkrbc` but the actual command is `ruby -r exerb/mkexy`.