# running ruby as a windows exe program

Tags: ruby

can we use our Ruby code to generate a Windows executable program, is it possible even if one of the required libraries is not from the stranded Ruby (like Qt or MySql) ???

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348919/building-a-windows-executable-from-my-ruby-app

Comment: I don't understand the why this has at least two downvotes. It seems like a valid question, and it wasn't downvoted that much the first time it was asked.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is [Ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra); heck, I liked it so much I sent in a patch to add Bundler support to it! Anyways, I know for a fact that it can include local DLLs (i.e. as required for SQLite or MySQL) along with the app.

Comment: I use it too, but there is one problem: you need to move program through most of its functions to make ocra see, which libraries it needs, and also you must close program manually, because ocra will not stop.

Comment: I pretty recently added another patch to Ocra to get around this problem, albeit at the cost of increased executable size: the --no-dep-run option skips the part where it runs the program to detect usage, and the --add-all-core option just includes all Ruby core libraries, which doesn't use up as much space as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JRuby to package it up in a jar or war.

This is an old link, but it might be helpful http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/bryan_weber/jruby_script_in_a_signed.html

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 3 seconds to find [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/) on Google.  Sounds like it includes the necessary libraries as well.